# How to follow redirect from javascript in cucumber?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cucumber, acceptance-testing, capybara

I have a a button (not a submit button) which does ajax calls before submitting another form.

What I want to do is

```
Given I am viewing homepage
When I press "JustAButton"
Then I should be on "/users/home"
```

But the redirection happens somewhat late and "Then" statement fails considering that the page is still in homepage. How can I wait till the ajax calls (that result from clicking the button) are finished and the page gets submitter??

Any ideas?

**EDIT : Sample javascript code**

For

```
<input type="button" id="btn_Send" value="Send"/>
```

Javascript is (pls ignore the syntax errors, I think you would get the overall idea)

```
document.ready(){
$("#btn_Send").click(function(){
   ajax.post('some url',<params>, callbackForSuccess);
}

function callbackForSuccess(result){
   $("#form1").submit();
}
```

Comment: Are you running that Cucumber scenario with a driver that supports Javascript e.g. Selenium? If not, the javascript/ajax on your page won't execute when your scenario runs.

Comment: @sidane, yea i am doing it. normal ajax calls are being handled properly. but when there are javascript form submits, it does not recognise them

Comment: Ok. And this behaviour works if you test it manually in the browser? Can you post any of your code to give a clearer idea of what you're doing?

Comment: I have added an edit. And it works manually in the browser. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Correct - "I should be on" performs the assertion immediately, before the JavaScript has a chance to load another pager.

You will need to define a step that waits until the browser is on a specified page (or timeout).